# How can I query by multiple fields quickly in MongoDb on terabytes of data?

Tags: mongodb, lucene

I need to store 1 - 20 terabytes of documents. Each document have binary data and metadata. Binary data can varies from a few kilobytes to several megabytes (text files, images, audio, video). Metadata is a list of key-value pairs. For example; id:  123
data: blob (several Kb)
fileType: doc
fileName: antibiotics_ar4.doc
path: \datacenter\medicine\antibiotics_ar4.doc
created: 01.01.2014 15:00:30
keywords: [«antibiotic», «medicine», «SomeFirm, Inc»]
field6: …
fieldN: …

I need:

- to insert data into a storage. I have from 1 to 20 inserting threads, each of them have almost 1 megabyte per second.
- to search in the storage without significant delays (5-10 seconds max). I have 2-3 concurrent users at a peak time.

User can search top 10-1000 files by:

- only keywords (antibiotic + medicine)
- keywords + created (medicine + from 01.01.2014 to 03.03.2014)
- keywords + fileType (medicine + xls)

For fulltext search I want to use Lucene/Elastic Search/Solr but what about search by dates, integers, Strings (with a few options like red, green, yellow, blue) in a single query? Server side will be written in java.

How can I do it in MongoDb? What I should to do: create index on each field or something else?

Comment: No. "Is this a <insert your opinion>" is not a suitable question here. Please re-phrase if you want a specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use GridFS
2. Use GridFS's metadata "feature"
3. Create a text index on the metadata field you want to search
4. Done - without Lucene

EDIT:

In the comments it was asked if a text search can span multiple fields. While each collection can have only one text index, this index may include multiple fields.

```
// Update a previously saved file with tags
// Import skipped for readability
db.fs.files.update({filename:"VeryImportantDocument.docx"},{$set:{tags:["foo","bar","baz"]}})

/* Create the index
   As you can see, there are multiple fields which together will
   provide the entries in the index 
*/
db.fs.files.ensureIndex({"tags":"text",filename:"text"});

db.fs.files.find({$text:{$search:"FOO"}})
> {"_id":... //Abbreviated result. Tags can be searched with that index

// search for filetypes is also possible (via extension, not mime-type, of course)
db.fs.files.find({$text:{$search:"docx"}})
> {"_id":...

db.fs.files.find({$text:{$search:"very"})
>{} // No result, searches for parts have to be done via the regex operator
db.fs.files.find({"filename":{$regex:"VeRy",$options:"i"}})
> {"_id":...
```

As for the dates: If you have a uniform format you can be sure of (because of the parsing or something), you can add another part of the query:

```
db.fs.files.find({"uploadDate":{$gte:startOfTimeFrame,$lte:EndOfTimeFrame}})
```

This of course can be combined with the other queries by the usual logical operators.

Comment: Thanks. And what about search with multiple fields? For example, text and date and file extension.

Comment: It heavily depends on wether you want the search to be adaptable or not. As long as you only have to search those three fields together (or a combination of two of them), it might well be that implementing the search parsing and doing the searches with mongoDB is easier to maintain and equally complicated to implement than with Lucene. In case it is foreseeable or sure that the requirements change, go with Lucene. But a sharded GridFS is definitely what you want to use, unless you can guarantee that you will *always* be under 16MB/document, in which cases you can use a standard DB  in mongo.

Comment: As I understand from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-types/#index-type-list ,I can create one text index for content of doc, one multikey index for predefined categories with low cardinality (10-50 items), one single field index for creation datetime, one single field index for file extension (also low cardinality)

But what about the low cardinality index? As I know low cardinality index is the enemy of good performance. I can create date/time + extension compound index, but what about date/time + tags compound index? Tags field can have multiple values. Can mongo create such index?

Comment: It is not possible to create a text index for the content of saved files in mongoDB. You can only create indices over fields. It wasn't clear that the document's content needs to be searchable, too.

Comment: Of couse, my mistake. I have a blob field (bytes, such as doc or pdf) and a content field (String, extracted text). I will be search text by content only, not blob.

Comment: In this case I would do a text index on the content, the tags and the filename, as the filename may bear semantical importance and search by file extension is automatically possible without additional (and redundant) metadata to deal with plus you can do an index only search for all regex searches. Actually, you can create the text index to be a compound index with the date index, since your query will have a normalized form searching in the content, for the filename and filextension and date (range) in one form or the other. That should result in a fairly quick index only search.